# Sql login failed in dotnetnuke(dnn)

Tags: sql-server-2008, dotnetnuke, failed-installation

I am trying to install dotnetnuke in my localhost but not able to installing dnn and below connection string used in webconfig file.

```
<add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Server=(local);Database=d1;uid=;pwd=;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Below error getting:

[image]

I am installing dnn in local host, please help to out this headache installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Integrated will attempted to use Windows Authentication for the database connection.

You either need to create a SQL authentication account and choose the "User Defined" option, or you need to add the user for your app pool to SQL to give it access to the D1 database.

I prefer to just use SQL Auth accounts, always ends up easier in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you, I will check and updated your answer. @Chris Hammond